# Laravel Vuejs Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk blogs-component failed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Laravel + Vuejs project and while everything works fine on local development, 2 pages are throwing the ChunkLoadError.

I have looked at other issues on SO, and checked my output path, file is really there.

Page is here : https://dev.trouveruncouvreur.ca/guide-toiture and same for https://dev.trouveruncouvreur.ca/city/d-soumission-couvreur-toiture-Brossard

Error is here :
[image: ChunkLoadError]

The chunk is available if you click on the link https://dev.trouveruncouvreur.ca/js/blogs-component.js

Edit: I deleted the project from the dev server, and reinstalled everything without success. I keep having the same issue. I did install on another server I have access to, and the error is gone, pages are all served correctly. We just found out client on dev server is using Cloudflare, so once we have acces, we can delete cache and see how it goes.

Comment: there are hundreds of reasons that may couse this, like proxy, file permition, firewall etc... can you give us more details about this error? there are no chuck erros in the given link.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKsn2.png)

Comment: I'll gladly add any more details you would see fit. Ok seems like you did have the page and blog to display, I only see the header/footer, the center of the page is only white. I deleted cache, tried private navigation, used another browser (Firefox) and always have this error.

Comment: all works fine on my side :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, Cloudflare's cache was the culprid. All vues files/chunk are now correctly served.